# Add lower and upper bounds on decision variables in Pyomo

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, python, pyomo

I have the following optimization model in pyomo:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory


model = pyo.ConcreteModel()


dictCostMatrix = {
    ('Ho', 'Dao'): 139.0,
    ('Ho', 'Co'): 135.0,
    ('Ho', 'Deo'): 134.0,
    ('Ho', 'Ao'): 132.0,
    ('Bo', 'Dao'): 176.0,
    ('Bo', 'Co'): 178.0,
    ('Bo', 'Deo'): 171.0,
    ('Bo', 'Ao'): 173.0,
    ('Hn', 'Dan'): 160.5,
    ('Hn', 'Cn'): 156.5,
    ('Hn', 'Den'): 155.5,
    ('Hn', 'An'): 153.5,
    ('Bn', 'Dan'): 157.5,
    ('Bn', 'Cn'): 159.5,
    ('Bn', 'Den'): 152.5,
    ('Bn', 'An'): 154.5,
    ('Dao', 'Dan'): 20.0,
    ('Co', 'Cn'): 20.0,
    ('Deo', 'Den'): 20.0,
    ('Ao', 'An'): 20.0
    }

upperBounds = {
    ('Ho', 'Dao'): 200,
    ('Ho', 'Co'): 200,
    ('Ho', 'Deo'): 200,
    ('Ho', 'Ao'): 200,
    ('Bo', 'Dao'): 200,
    ('Bo', 'Co'): 200,
    ('Bo', 'Deo'): 200,
    ('Bo', 'Ao'): 200,
    ('Hn', 'Dan'): 250,
    ('Hn', 'Cn'): 250,
    ('Hn', 'Den'): 250,
    ('Hn', 'An'): 250,
    ('Bn', 'Dan'): 250,
    ('Bn', 'Cn'): 250,
    ('Bn', 'Den'): 250,
    ('Bn', 'An'): 250,
    ('Dao', 'Dan'): 50,
    ('Co', 'Cn'): 50,
    ('Deo', 'Den'): 50,
    ('Ao', 'An'): 50
    }

lowerBounds = {
    ('Ho', 'Dao'): 0,
    ('Ho', 'Co'): 0,
    ('Ho', 'Deo'): 0,
    ('Ho', 'Ao'): 0,
    ('Bo', 'Dao'): 0,
    ('Bo', 'Co'): 0,
    ('Bo', 'Deo'): 0,
    ('Bo', 'Ao'): 0,
    ('Hn', 'Dan'): 0,
    ('Hn', 'Cn'): 0,
    ('Hn', 'Den'): 0,
    ('Hn', 'An'): 0,
    ('Bn', 'Dan'): 0,
    ('Bn', 'Cn'): 0,
    ('Bn', 'Den'): 0,
    ('Bn', 'An'): 0,
    ('Dao', 'Dan'): 0,
    ('Co', 'Cn'): 0,
    ('Deo', 'Den'): 0,
    ('Ao', 'An'): 0
    }


# create components of the optimization program
model.i = pyo.Set(initialize=dictCostMatrix.keys())
model.x = pyo.Var(model.i, bounds=(0,None), within=Integers)
model.c = pyo.Param(model.i, initialize=dictCostMatrix)


# objective function
def objective(model):
    return sum(model.c[i]*model.x[i] for i in model.i)
model.obj = pyo.Objective(rule=objective, sense=minimize)
```

Each key in each of the dictionaries represents a pair of nodes that are connected. *dictCostMatrix* shows the cost of the arc between the two nodes (e.g. the cost from 'Ho' to 'Dao' is 139. The dictionaries *upperBounds* and *lowerBounds* are describing the lower and upper bound of allowable flow between the node pairs.

From this, I want to make constraints on **model.x** (the decision variables) with upper and lower bounds. I would like to use the dictionaries *upperBounds* and *lowerBounds* for this. Is there a clever way of doing this?

Comment: Hi @Telso. If you search for "Pyomo set bounds" in Google the first hit I get is https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_modeling_components/Variables.html In the bottom, it is shown how to set bounds